# How to Change color of drawing if drawing is overlapping in flutter drawio?

Tags: flutter, web

I am making an app in flutter to draw shapes, for it I am using `flutter_drawio`.

I need to restrict/change color of a drawing or a shape that overlaps previous shape or a drawing.

[image]

I want the box on top tobe in red. Any help would be appreciated.